# Right To Left text in mono windows forms

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, ubuntu, mono

I Opened my .net project in monoDevelop to use it on Linux. It works. But I cannot view Arabic fonts in Controls Text in a good format on Ubuntu. I view reverse letters from Left to Right. But Arabic is Right to Left. I changed the font to Tahoma and I used Right to Left Layout but it doesn't work. Just Arabic text in title bar looks good. But Button, Label, TextBox and others have same problems.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Mono-RTL-support-td4663203.html;cid=1404449897232-646

As explained by @Rafael Teixeira, "WinForms in Mono is not actively maintained by the core team anymore, but if volunteers do come forward with well-tested contributions as pull requests these can be merged in...".